# Scrollable tabhost in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-scrollview

I have made a scrollable tabhost in android. It has around 5 tabs. Adding new tabs shrink the previous ones so that it fits in the entire screen.. it adopts to scroll only in extreme cases like having about 6+ tabs.
Is there a method to specify the number of tabs visible at a time?
I would like that only 3 of them be visible at a time so that each of them have good enough width.

Specifying  tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(position).getLayoutParams().width
did not help

Answer (score 0):

For just tabs.. just keep check on no of tabs using variable. Now as per the variables value add that many no of tabs to your activity.

Comment: i want all tabs present, but needs to resize the tab size so tat only a few are visible at a time rather than the tabs shrinking so that maximum of them are accommodated.